# Is there any faster way to order data across columns within each row - R

Tags: r, data.table, rowwise

Suppose I have the following data

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "z"), v2 = c("y", "b"), v3 = c("m", "n"))

v1 v2 v3
 a  y  m  
 z  b  n
```

What is the fastest way to create 3 new columns with ordered data like the following?

```
v1 v2 v3 alphabetical_1 alphabetical_2 alphabetical_3
 a  y  m              a              m              y
 z  b  n              b              n              z
```

I have thousands of rows of data like this.

Comment: `df[paste0('alphabetical_', seq_along(df))] <- t(apply(df, 1, sort))`

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks a lot Ronak.  Your comment was really helpful!